# Scala List.filter with two conditions, applied only once

Tags: scala

Don't know if this is possible, but I have some code like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
val evens = list.filter { e => e % 2 == 0 }

if(someCondition) {
  val result = evens.filter { e => e % 3 == 0 }
} else {
  val result = evens.filter { e => e % 5 == 0 }
}
```

But I don't want to iterate over all elements twice, so is there a way that I can create a "generic pick-all-the-evens numbers on this collection" and apply some other function, so that it would only iterate once?

Comment: in your example there would only one iteration over initial list, other filters will be applied to a new filtered (smaller) collection, can you please clarify what you want to achieve

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you turn `list` into a lazy collection, such as an `Iterator`, then you can apply all the filter operations (or other things like `map` etc) in one pass:

```
val list = (1 to 12).toList
val doubleFiltered: List[Int] =
  list.iterator
    .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
    .filter(_ % 3 == 0)
    .toList
println(doubleFiltered)
```

When you convert the collection to an Iterator with `.iterator`, Scala will keep track of the operations to be performed (here, two `filter`s), but will wait to perform them until the result is actually accessed (here, via the call to `.toList`).

So I might rewrite your code like this:

```
val list = (1 to 12).toList
val evens = list.iterator.filter(_ % 2 == 0)

val result = 
  if(someCondition)
    evens.filter(_ % 3 == 0)
  else
    evens.filter(_ % 5 == 0)

result foreach println
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you might want an `Iterator`, a `Stream`, or a `View`.  They are all lazily computed (so the one-pass aspect will apply), but they differ on things like whether they can be iterated over multiple times (`Stream` and `View`) or whether they keep the computed value around for later access (`Stream`).

To really see these different lazy behaviors, try running this bit of code and set `<OPERATION>` to either `toList`, `iterator`, `view`, or `toStream`:

```
val result =
  (1 to 12).<OPERATION>
    .filter { e => println("filter 1: " + e); e % 2 == 0 }
    .filter { e => println("filter 2: " + e); e % 3 == 0 }
result foreach println
result foreach println
```

Here's the behavior you will see:

- `List` (or any other non-lazy collection): Each `filter` is requires a separate iteration through the collection.  The resulting filtered collection is stored in memory so that each `foreach` can just display it.
- `Iterator`: Both `filter`s and the first `foreach` are done in a single iteration.  The second `foreach` does nothing since the `Iterator` has been consumed.  Results are not stored in memory.
- `View`: Both `foreach` calls result in their own single-pass iteration over the collection to perform the `filters`.  Results are not stored in memory.
- `Stream`: Both `filter`s and the first `foreach` are done in a single iteration.  The resulting filtered collection is stored in memory so that each `foreach` can just display it.

Comment: In my tests, only "view" iterates once. When I call toIterator on a traversable collection, it iterates over the collection before I call toList. Only using "view" I've seen it iterating only after a "toList" call. But

Comment: +1 great answer, thanks. JVM performance is so good in general that you don't notice inefficient List operations...until you do ;-) iterator version of someList.filter(x=> otherList.contains(x.id)) is at least 2X as fast.

Answer (score 8):

<s>You could use function composition. `someCondition` here is only called once, when deciding which function to compose with:</s>

```
def modN(n: Int)(xs: List[Int]) = xs filter (_ % n == 0)

val f = modN(2) _ andThen (if (someCondition) modN(3) else modN(5))

val result = f(list)
```

(This doesn't do what you want - it still traverses the list twice)

Just do this:

```
val f: Int => Boolean = if (someCondition) { _ % 3 == 0 } else { _ % 5 == 0 }
val result = list filter (x => x % 2 == 0 && f(x))
```

or maybe better:

```
val n = if (someCondition) 3 else 5
val result = list filter (x => x % 2 == 0 && x % n == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work:

```
list.filter{e => e % 2 == 0 && (if (someCondition) e % 3 == 0 else e % 5 == 0)}
```

also FYI `e % 2 == 0` is going to give you all the even numbers, unless you're naming the val `odds` for another reason.

Comment: Wouldn't `someCondition` be checked `list.size` times?

Comment: sure, I was under the assumption that it was just a value.  If it's a function call or complex operation then the result could just be set to a val before the filter operation.

Comment: It will only be checked if the first part of the statement, `e % 2 == 0` is true.

Comment: I would extract the condition to something like `val n = if (condition) 3 else 5; list.filter(e => e%2==0 && e%n==0)` (which of course will only work if the condition is stable)

Answer (score 1):

You just write two conditions in the filter:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

var result = List(0)
val someCondition = true

result = if (someCondition) list.filter { e => e % 2 == 0 && e % 3 == 0 }
         else               list.filter { e => e % 2 == 0 && e % 5 == 0 }
```