# getting list by the first element in the list of lists

Tags: scala

Hi I am new to scala and getting silly doubts, I have a list of lists which looks like this

```
(4,List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)))
```

I want to get the lists which starts with 4. How to do it.

Comment: you said you have `List` of `List` but `(4,List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)))` is `List[Any]` or a tuple. what is `4` in there?

Comment: sorry for that, i have a data structure which looks something like this (Int, List(List)). Now from the list of lists I want only those lists which starts with Int provided in the start.

Comment: Okay, your data is of type `Tuple2[Int, List[List[Int]]]`, see the answer and let me if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `filter` to traverse through the `List` and apply your predicate on each list to check if first elem is `4`.

example:

```
scala> val (data, options) = (4, List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)))
data: Int = 4
options: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4))

scala> options.filter(_.headOption.contains(data))
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4))
```

Also see: [Scala List.filter with two conditions, applied only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183768/432903)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

Here is another

```
listOfLists.collect{ case l @ 4 :: _ => l}
```

Potentially more powerful because we can filter on the first n elements, e.g.

```
listOfLists.collect{ case l @ 4 :: 0 :: 1 :: _ => l}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Tuple `(Int, List[List[Int]])`, and want to return Lists that start with the `Int` provided in the start, for this case `4`:
I would recommend you do something like this:

```
val myTuple = (4,List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)))

myTuple._2.filter(_.headOption.contains(myTuple._1))
```

And this will return `List(List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4))`

What we are doing here is, we are first accessing the `List[List[Int]]` in the Tuple by doing `myTuple._2` then we filter to remove Lists that don't have a head value as 4 - which we passed in as `myTuple._1`.

Note we are using `headOption` instead of `head` to get the first element in a List, this is to handle exceptions where no List contains the value provided in the start, for this case `4` (more details on this can be found here http://www.bks2.com/blog/2012/12/31/head_vs_headOption/)

Answer (score 0):

```
val t = (4, List(List(2, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(3, 4, 0, 2, 4), List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4)))
t._2.filter(_.head==t._1)
```

**In REPL:**

```
scala> t._2.filter(_.head==t._1)
res5: List[List[Int]] = List(List(4, 0, 1, 2, 4))
```